# YouTube videos posted to Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

The format of posting YouTube videos to Facebook has changed. The selection of where I can post on Facebook makes no sense-friends of friends, etc.  When I post a YouTube video to my wall only, nothing appears there, as then I would re-post it to a group. I can only think it's my older Mac computer or there is a setting somewhere I can't find. I cannot post to a group, it doesn't give me that option and I can't seem to create that option; I preferred the older set-up better  I would mean that I would have to post to friends to get it on my wall (maybe) and then re-post it to a group, if I'm given that option-sometimes there is no ability to share on your post.

Answer (score 0):

I have 4 Facebook pages, I experienced this as well, and here is how I solved it:

1. I log into one of my Facebook pages.
2. I then open another tab or browser, then log in to YouTube.
3. I select the video, click the "share" button beneath, and a small box pops up connected to the particular Facebook page in which I am logged, and it includes the video.
4. I add any text that I wish that speaks about the video and click "Send."
5. As proof of the post, I refresh my particular Facebook page that I am logged into, and there is the video.

After clicking the "share" button underneath the video, I then select the blue "f" (Facebook) graphic link BEFORE the window pops up.